# Unique solution of cyclic system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the system of equations: 
$$\begin{cases}
y^3-9x^2+27x-27=0, \\
z^3-9y^2+27y-27=0, \\
x^3-9z^2+27z-27=0.
\end{cases}$$

I noted that if we add all three equations we get: $(x-3)^3+(y-3)^3+(z-3)^3=0$.

Also from the first equation we have: $y^3=9x^2-27x+27$ and mininal value of RHS is $\frac{27}{4}$. Hence $y\ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$. Thus $x,y,z \ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$. I guuess that that this system has the unique solution which is $x=y=z=3$ but I can't prove it.

I would be very grateful to anyone's help!

Comment: Incidentally, one can also express your system in the nice form, $$y^3 - x^3 + (x - 3)^3 = 0\\z^3 - y^3 + (y - 3)^3=0\\x^3 - z^3 + (z - 3)^3=0$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, What does it give to us?

Comment: Well, it shows that each equation is a sum of three cubes. Also, it makes it very easy to see that their sum is also a sum of three cubes $(x-3)^3+(y-3)^3+(z-3)^3 =0$ as was pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $f$ be a function such that  $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{9x^2-27x+27}$. Then you are looking for a fixed point $x$ of the funciton $x \mapsto f(f(f(x)))$. You could probably apply the Banach fixed point theorem to show the uniqueness.

Comment: I guess that I must to show that $f$ is contraction mapping right?

Comment: Yes, if you can show that $f$ is a contraction, the repetition of $f$ will also be a contractoin! Another hint: $f$ is a contraction where $f|'(x)|<1$.

Comment: Why you consider $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{9x^2-27x+27}$ but not $f(x)=9x^2-27x+27$?

Comment: You can rewrite your system as $\begin{cases}
y=\sqrt[3]{9x^2-27x+27}=0, \\
z=\sqrt[3]{9y^2-27y+27}=0, \\
x=\sqrt[3]{9z^2-27z+27}=0.
\end{cases}$ Then you can easily see that if you find a fixed point of $x \mapsto f(f(f(x)))$ you get a solution of your system.

Comment: Also if $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{9x^2-27x+27}$ what form has $f(f(f(x)))$? I wrote it but it's little bit hard :(

Comment: Why you put $x=y=z=0$ above?

Comment: Oh sorry, the $=0$ should be ignored in the equation above, that was just a copy paste error. You obviously do not have to write out $f(f(f(x)))$ explicitly, as we said, it is sufficient to prove the contraction property for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Using resultants (elimination theory) one can eliminate $y$ using the first two equations, getting

$z^9-81z^6+6561x^2z^3-59049x^4-19683xz^3+354294x^3+21870z^3-885735x^2+1062882x-551124=0$

Similarly between that and the first equation eliminate $z$, and after removing the factor $(x-3)^3$ from that get the polynomial

$x^{24}+9x^{23}+54x^{22}+27x^{21}-972x^{20}-8019x^{19}+40095x^{18}+10117062x^{17}+61056666x^{16}+293316066x^{15}+3201577731x^{14}+110875067271x^{13}+362437979031x^{12}+1306649735172x^{11}+37698094171215x^{10}+114790725090441x^9+588199220321805x^8-596835210442104x^7+150911882159463594x^6-1359671465592849168x^5+5434067661760469385x^4-12178267271135182143x^3+16353330388363013751x^2-12568395108363762114x+4508627169830615244=0$

That polynomial has only complex roots.  Conclusion, the only real solution to your problem is $x=y=z=3$.

Comment: Oh my God! :) +1!

Comment: @jbuddenh: Hmm, remember [this octic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145145/on-the-solvable-octic-x8-x729x229-0) from the old sci.math?

Comment: I do not understand any of your approach: Given two equations, what does a *resultant* exactly provide? How did you see that the polynomial of degree 24 has only complex roots? When you are already using a CAS what does this way (I assume you did not calculate it by hand) what benefit do you get when contrasted with just plugging the original equations into a CAS?

Comment: @flawr:  yes, I used a CAS.  Resultant enables you to algebraically eliminate variables.  Often easier than Grobner bases.  I have great confidence in CAS computation of resultants, but very little confidence in CAS reporting all solutions of a system of polynomial equations without either resultants or Grobner.  As for all complex roots, none of the imaginary parts is near 0, so not really an issue.  There may well be a simple way to show that the obvious solution of the system is the only real solution.  If so, I hope someone will post it.